# 'If string not equal' doesn't work the way I expect in AutoIt

Tags: string, operators, autoit

I wrote this code in AutoIt (v3.3.8.1):

```
$x = 'dog'
if not $x = 'hello' Then
   ConsoleWrite("fish")
Else
   ConsoleWrite("world")
EndIf
```

Don't you think the output should be "fish"? But instead it says "world". What's up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of [operator precedence](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_operators.htm). Contrary to other languages, like BASIC and Perl, in AutoIt `not` has higher precedence than equality. Change the code to

```
if not ($x = 'hello') then
```

or

```
if $x <> 'hello' then
```